# calculating the precision and recall for a specific threshhold

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I have a logistic regression model in which I calculate the tpr, fpr and thresholds using the roc_curve. After looking at the accuracy rates for different thresholds, I found the most optimal threshold to be 0.63. I have been told that I need to calculate the new precision and recall based on the most optimal threshold which in this case is 0.63. Is there any way to this calculation is python?

Answer (score 1):

```
y_pred = log_reg.predict_proba(X)[:, 1] > 0.63
print(precision_score(y_true, y_pred), recall_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the ground truth results `y_true` and also the corresponding model predictions `y_pred`, you can use SciKit-Learn's [**precision_recall_fscore_support**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html).

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support

y_true = ...                             # read from a file or wherever
y_pred = logistic_model.predict(x_test)  # your model that has been "fit" using e.g. x_train

# Perform any further steps required to classify predictions as TP, FP, etc.

# Compute precision, recall, f1_score and number of occurences of each label
precision, recall, f1, counts = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred)
```